# Constructing Venn diagrams for combinations of three events

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

The question is as follows:

> An experiment involves choosing an integer n between $0$ and $9$. The sample space con- sists of all integers 0..9. Let $A = \{n ≤ 5\}$, $B = \{3 ≤ n ≤ 7\}$, $C = \{n\text{ is even and } n > 0\}$. List the points that belong to the following events

(1) ABC;

(2) $A \cup (B \setminus  C)$

I am comparing answers with my classmate and we agree on the answer for 1. We disagree on number 2. I am under the impression that since 4 is an included outcome of A, it should be in the resultant outcomes which denote the answer. My classmate believes that 4 should not be included. We compared each other's diagrams and came up with the following (mine was messier so I am including my partner's):

[image]

So to generalize the question without telling us the answer, does a negation of a particular subset affect the subset on the other side of the operation (union or intersect) ?

[original, larger  image](https://i.imgur.com/2nzVN86.jpeg)

Comment: It is better to include images using the built-in "image" button in the editor. The regular imgur-uploaded images may expire. I reuploaded the image from your post.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct; it has no effect on the other side of a union. Since $4 \in A$, we know that $4 \in A \cup (B \cap \overline C)$. Also note that since $3 \leq 5 \leq 7$, your $5$ is in the wrong spot; it should be in the overlap between $A$ and $B$ but not $C$. Also don't forget to label $9$ in your Venn diagram (it's outside all $3$ events).

In the end, you should get that:
$$
A \cup (B \cap \overline C) = \{0,1,2,3,4,5\} \cup \{3,5,7\} = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,7\}
$$